# Use the binomial theorem and the convolution identity to express in compact form the expression for the product of

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Sum of c^(2(n-k))*(2n choose 2k)*x^(2k) from 2k=0 to 2n with sum of c^((2(n-k))-1)*(2n choose 2k+1)*x^(2k+1) from 2k+1=0 to 2n where c is an element of the set of rational numbers not 0

I found the compact form for both sums to be:
((c+x)^2n+(c-x)^2n)/2 = Sum of c^(2(n-k))*(2n choose 2k)*x^(2k) from 2k=0 to 2n
((c+x)^2n-(c-x)^2n)/2 = Sum of c^((2(n-k))-1)*(2n choose 2k+1)*x^(2k+1) from 2k+1=0 to 2n

But at this point, I'm stuck. I don't know how to use the convolution identity here to express the product of the polynomials.

I would appreciate it if you could give me some insight as to what the right approach should be here.

Apologies for not formatting this (not familiar with the Tex methods).

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for a quick note on using mathematical notation (with links to more detailed tutorial and reference material).  In particular the command for the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is `\binom{n}{k}`.

Comment: A better setup to your Question would be appreciated.  What (kind of thing) is $c$?  What you've written about the index of summation limits should probably be stated in terms of $k$ (rather than $2k$ or $2k+1$).  Give a title that will alert Readers to what your problem is about, but don't use it as a "run-on" introduction to the body of the Question.  The body allows you to elaborate the *context* of your problem (e.g. what motivates it, what makes it important to you).

Comment: c is any rational number excluding 0. Index summation limit for the first sum is 0≤2k≤2n and for the second sum its 0≤2k+1≤2n. I will edit this question if it's still not clear. Also, how do I attach a screenshot here? Thanks.